# Rewrite jQuery Validate piece of code for Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-validate

The following code is working great for all browsers except for Internet Explorer.

Can anyone please tell me what to change in it for Internet Explorer to like it?

Thanks a ton

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $.getScript( "http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js", dependsOnValidate );
});

function dependsOnValidate() {

  $.validator.setDefaults({ submitHandler: function() { alert( "Valid" ); } });

  $("#form_login").validate({
    rules: {
        EMAIL: {
            required: true,
          email: true
        },
        PASS: {
            required: true,
          minlength: 4
        },
        },
    messages: {
        EMAIL: " need a valid email",   
        PASS: {
        required: " required",
        minlength: " too short"
        }
        }
  });   

} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PASS: {
                required: true,
              minlength: 4
            },
```

delete the last comma in this block of code, IE doesn't like extra commas in JSON

Later edit: complete correct code:

```
$(function() {
    $.getScript( "http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js", dependsOnValidate );
});

function dependsOnValidate() {

  $.validator.setDefaults({ submitHandler: function() { alert( "Valid" ); } });

  $("#form_login").validate({
    rules: {
        EMAIL: {
            required: true,
          email: true
        },
        PASS: {
            required: true,
          minlength: 4
        }
        },
    messages: {
        EMAIL: " need a valid email",   
        PASS: {
        required: " required",
        minlength: " too short"
        }
        }
  });   

}
```

Comment: Thanks matei, but I cannot delete it, that's the closing for rules: if I delete it I get an error: missing } after property list

Comment: yes, sorry, I misread the indentation , it's formated correctly. do you get an error message ?

Comment: You know Internet Explorer, the error is: "Expected identifier, string or number" pointing to an empty line ..

Comment: you were right is the comma! it was cahed before, and the error was thrown because I deleted the } in a second try. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: yes :) I know it.  in fact I think I was right, but you deleted the wrong comma. You need to delete the comma right after the `PASS {}` ,  not the one before `messages:` . I'll  put the whole code in my answer to be more clear